# label na vertical no VB

Tags: vb.net

Como faço pra fazer com que o texto do label fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na vertical e de baixo para cima.
Creio que seja simples mas não estou conseguindo.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Adicione o código do seu componente asp.net ou o html renderizado da sua página

Comment: Desculpe se não entendi direito, mas eu preciso de um codigo que deixe um label no vb conforme a imagem acima, ainda não tenho um codigo que possa ajudar.

Comment: Aqui tem a solução para o seu problema
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11523/Vertical-Label-Control-in-VB-NET

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! tambem achei esse aqui pra quem quiser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597121/how-do-i-rotate-a-label-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, você pode usar o "writing-mode" no HTML(HTML5), segue exemplo abaixo:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="teste" Style="writing-mode: vertical-lr;">exemplo de texto</asp:Label>
```